# $ php bin/magento module:list , returning php version error message while my php version is supported

Tags: magento2

It Returning

```
php bin/magento module:list
```

> PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

My php version is 7.0.10

Answer (score 0):

it seems `openssl` is loading twice. go to php.ini, find the below code, if it is placed in twice, comment/remove the second one.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

restart the apache and check it once.